# Настройка границ ячеек у QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Есть ли возможность в QTableWidget определенным ячейкам задавать свой стиль отображения границ? Некоторые группы ячеек в моей таблице содержат информацию, которую необходимо визуально отделить от всех остальных ячеек.
Интересует возможность изменения толщины, цвета и может можно вообще убрать какую-либо из границ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить стиль можно, через [Qt Style Sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

Вот пример: [Customizing QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview)

QTableWidget производный от QTableView, так что всё должно работать